# Abstracting require.ensure boilerplate from react-router getComponent doesn't work

Tags: webpack, react-router

I'm using code splitting in webpack with react-router and to load components async I do this:

```
<Route
  path="somePath"
  getComponent={(next, cb) => {
    require.ensure([], (require) => {
      cb(null, require('../components/Example.jsx'));
    });
  }
}
/>
```

Now after checking out [Henley Edition's article](http://henleyedition.com/implicit-code-splitting-with-react-router-and-webpack/) I tried doing something like this to avoid use bundle-loader and still reduce boilerplate.

```
const loadLazy = (component) => {
  return (next, cb) => {
    require.ensure([], (require) => {
      cb(null, require(component));
    });
  };
};

...

<Route
  path="somePath"
  getComponent={lazyLoad('../components/Example.jsx')}
/>
```

But this throws error in console saying Cannot find module '../components/Example.jsx'.

Why does this not work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`require.ensure` doesn't work with dynamic module paths (like your `require(component)`) which is why the article you reference used [Webpack's bundle-loader](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/bundle-loader) instead to get around this limitation.